# QDialog & shadow possible?

Tags: qt, shadow, qwidget, qdialog

Is it possible to draw background shadow in a custom QDialog?

I want to add a light shadow behind the custom QDialog.

Thanks

Comment: look here...http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/demos-embeddeddialogs.html

Comment: Here is a QPainter implementation, no flag option is avaliable?